# Saml Authentication Request Protocol Id

Tags: security, authentication, request, protocols, saml

When doing Http Redirect Binding with SAML2.0 protocol I should send to the Identity Provider structure like this:

```
<q1:AuthnRequest 
         ID="{82AB4AE6-919C-5FE6-C843-8342E6F9AB61}" Version="2.0" 
           IssueInstant="2011-02-22T09:19:48+0100" 
           Destination="https://test.server.com/Service.jsf" 
           IsPassive="false" 
           AssertionConsumerServiceURL="http://myservice.com/sso/" 
          xmlns:q1="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"> 
          <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">test.server.com</Issuer>
</q1:AuthnRequest>
```

My question is: how is the value of `ID` generated?

`ID="{82AB4AE6-919C-5FE6-C843-8342E6F9AB61}" Version="2.0"`

What are the rules to generate it?

Answer (score 18):

The exact method of generating SAML IDs is not explicitly defined—it must merely conform to the standards of an XML ID. An XML ID is an xsd:NCName, which is derived from xsd:Name, which can't start with a number or contain spaces, and should have 160 bits of "randomness".

The simplest ID generator in Java that will satisfy that criteria is:

```
String id() {
  return "a" + UUID.randomUUID();
}
```

In addition, [OpenSAML](https://shibboleth.net/products/opensaml-java.html) ships with SecureRandomIdentifierGenerator as well:

```
// You will need to catch the NoSuchAlgorithmException during construction.
IdentifierGenerator idGenerator = new SecureRandomIdentifierGenerator();

String id() {
  return idGenerator.generateIdentifier();
}
```

The actual generation code looks like this:

```
SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");

String generateIdentifier() {
  return generateIdentifier(16);
}

String generateIdentifier(int size) {
  byte[] buf = new byte[size];
  random.nextBytes(buf);
  return "_".concat(new String(Hex.encode(buf)));
}
```

Yet another alternative pulled from [SAMLSSOUtil](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/saml/util/SAMLSSOUtil.java):

```
char[] charMapping = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p' };
Random random = new Random();

String createID() {
  byte[] bytes = new byte[20]; // 160 bits
  random.nextBytes(bytes);

  char[] chars = new char[40];

  for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
    int left = (bytes[i] >> 4) & 0x0f;
    int right = bytes[i] & 0x0f;
    chars[i * 2] = charMapping[left];
    chars[i * 2 + 1] = charMapping[right];
  }

  return String.valueOf(chars);
}
```

From the [Oasis](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) docs:

> The xs:ID simple type is used to declare SAML identifiers for assertions, requests, and responses. Values declared to be of type xs:ID in this specification MUST satisfy the following properties in addition to those imposed by the definition of the xs:ID type itself:
>
> • Any party that assigns an identifier MUST ensure that there is negligible probability that that party or any other party will accidentally assign the same identifier to a different data object.
> • Where a data object declares that it has a particular identifier, there MUST be exactly one such declaration.
>
> The mechanism by which a SAML system entity ensures that the identifier is unique is left to the implementation. In the case that a random or pseudorandom technique is employed, the probability of two randomly chosen identifiers being identical MUST be less than or equal to 2^-128 and SHOULD be less than or equal to 2^-160. This requirement MAY be met by encoding a randomly chosen value between 128 and 160 bits in length. The encoding must conform to the rules defining the xs:ID datatype. A pseudorandom generator MUST be seeded with unique material in order to ensure the desired uniqueness properties between different systems.
>
> The xs:NCName simple type is used in SAML to reference identifiers of type xs:ID since xs:IDREF cannot be used for this purpose. In SAML, the element referred to by a SAML identifier reference might actually be defined in a document separate from that in which the identifier reference is used. Using xs:IDREF would violate the requirement that its value match the value of an ID attribute on some element in the same XML document.

Answer (score 3):

id is an xsd:NCName which is derived from xsd:Name, which can't start with a number

simplest possible id in Java:

```
String id = new UID().toString().replaceAll(":", "-");
```

and never reuse that id with any other AuthnRequest otherwise you'll get a replay attack error if the IdP can detect that

Answer (score 2):

How you generate it is basically up to you. The only caveat is that it must be a valid XML ID type value (which means it can't start with a digit or contain any spaces).  You will need to persist it somewhere, so that you can match it against the Response the IdP sends.

Answer (score 1):

Sect 1.3.4 "ID and ID Reference Values" of the [SAML 2.0 Core](http://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf) Document.

Answer (score -1):

well it could be late but I think people looking for answer can get benefit...

you can refer to [SAMLUTIL](https://svn.wso2.org/repos/wso2/carbon/platform/trunk/components/identity/org.wso2.carbon.identity.sso.saml/src/main/java/org/wso2/carbon/identity/sso/saml/util/SAMLSSOUtil.java) which has many standard util methods.
For generating id you can refer to createID() method in this util.